# Conversor de divisas - Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy trabajando en un conversor de divisas pero no puedo lograr que me devuelta el resultado cuando el usuario elige dolar o euros. ¿Que estoy haciendo mal?.

```
let ingresarCantidad = Number(prompt("Ingrese una cantidad:"));
let ingresados = '';

while (ingresarCantidad != 0) {
    ingresados += ingresarCantidad +"\n";
    ingresarCantidad = prompt("Ingrese una cantidad:");
}

let elegirMoneda = prompt("¿Desea convertir a dolar o euro?")

function conversor(ingresarCantidad, elegirMoneda) {
    let dolar = 240;
    let euro = 260;

    if (elegirMoneda === dolar) {
        return alert(ingresarCantidad / dolar);
    } else if (elegirMoneda === euro){
        return alert(ingresarCantidad / euro);
    }
}

alert(conversor(ingresarCantidad, elegirMoneda));
```

Answer (score 0):

2 errores tienes.

1- En la funcion conversor tienes que eliminar la palabra alert en el return. ya que alert no devuelve nada y el alert ya lo tienes en la llamada a la función.
2- En la comprobación de la moneda a escoger, tienes que poner strings, ya que el usuario pondrá euro o dolar.

La función quedaría así.

```
function conversor(ingresarCantidad, elegirMoneda) {
    let dolar = 240;
    let euro = 260;

    if (elegirMoneda === "dolar") {
        return ingresarCantidad / dolar;
    } else if (elegirMoneda === "euro"){
        return ingresarCantidad / euro;
    }
}
```

También no se si hay un error o no, a mi me parece que si en el while. yo lo he cambiado por este:

```
while (isNaN(ingresarCantidad) === true) {
    ingresados += ingresarCantidad +"\n";
    ingresarCantidad = prompt("Ingrese una cantidad:");
}
```